# How can I make a Stack Overflow CV page?

Tags: support, developer-story

I recently saw this profile - https://stackoverflow.com/cv/daguej

How can I make one for myself?

Comment: Service has been shutdown. I made this clone before hand as I also enjoyed the look . https://github.com/jogboms/developer-story which I deployed at https://developer-story.vercel.app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your [Profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) (*not* Stack Overflow Meta), select [Edit Profile and Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) at the top, and then Developer Story Preferences on the left. You'll find the options for setting up your public link there.

Or navigate to *your* page directly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/15053425).

Comment: what's a story view and traditional view ?

Comment: Different views of the same page. You have linked to the "traditional" view in your question.

Comment: can you link a story view?

Comment: @anirudh You have two fields with two URLs, one for the traditional view and the other for the story view. Simply, copy the one you want after you make it public.

Comment: *"can you link a story view?"* Yes, just take the URL you posted in your original post and change "cv" to "story".

Comment: yeah I noticed that!

Answer (score 19):

#### You can't; not anymore.

The "Developer Story" feature was [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/4722345) on March 31, 2022:

> TL;DR – On March 31, 2022, we will discontinue Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story. This includes all job listings, saved searches, applications, messages, recommended job matches, job ads, developer story, saved resumes, and the salary calculator.